# Dynamically Building HTML Table with Javascript Object

Tags: javascript, html

Here I'm looping through an object and retrieving the key:value pairs and placing them in a table

```
obj = clickedRecord.toJSON(); //gets record from 
                              //separate table and converts to JSON format
var array=[];
for(key in obj) {
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      array.push(
         '<table id="myTable">' +
             '<tr>' +
               '<td>' + key + '</td>' +
               '<td>' + obj[key] + '</td>' +
             '<tr>' +
         '</table>''
      );
   }
}
```

The output of which is:

```
ID 100
,
Name Billy
,
Address 525 Park Lane
,
```

Is there a cleaner way to dynamically construct a table using a javascript Object, as well as omit the commas from the returned data?

Comment: Not really, unless you want to use jquery or Just straight DOM manipulation. Which is basically the same just with a couple of less lines.

Comment: Your output seems to be a string presentation of an array. Add `.join('')` to the end of the output expression.

Comment: Thanks @Teemu the .join('') did the trick. I just realized I'm making a table for each iteration of the loop-no bueno

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
   var table = document.createElement('TABLE');
   table.setAttribute("id", "myTable");

   for(key in obj) {
       var tr = document.createElement('TR');
       table.appendChild(tr);

       var td = document.createElement('TD');           
       td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(key));
       tr.appendChild(td);

       var td2 = document.createElement('TD');           
       td2.appendChild(document.createTextNode(obj[key]));
       tr.appendChild(td2);
   }
```

Comment: @ClayBanks No problem, glad to be of help.